# How to wait properly with Selenium until a list is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote Selenium code (in Javascript) to scroll down a list with the Down-key on the keyboard automatically. I know that you can scroll easier with a Javascript-command, but I want to do it with the Down-key.

This is my code so far:

```
  let list = await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#scrollableList')), 2000);

  // the list is not scrolled in the beginning:
  let scrolledY = await this.driver.executeScript('return arguments[0].scrollTop;', list);
  await assert.deepEqual(scrolledY, 0);

  // clicking on the list and pressing the "Down"-Key multiple times to scroll down
  await this.driver.actions({
    bridge: true
  }).click(list).perform();
  await this.driver.actions({
    bridge: true
  }).keyDown(Key.DOWN).keyUp(Key.DOWN).keyDown(Key.DOWN).keyUp(Key.DOWN).keyDown(Key.DOWN).keyUp(Key.DOWN).perform();

  // This is what I need so that the following assert return true:
  await sleep(100);

  // check if it is successfully scrolled down:
  scrolledY = await this.driver.executeScript('return arguments[0].scrollTop;', list);
  await assert.ok(scrolledY > 0);
```

My problem:
It scrolls down successfully (When I let the program sleep for 10 seconds, I can clearly see that). But I need the line `await sleep(100);` to wait a couple of milliseconds. Otherwise the last assert returns that it did not work.
Why is that and how can I make it work without the sleep command?

Comment: My guess is the JS command is executed separately moved on quickly to the assert. Can you try the same script with `this.driver.executeAsyncScript`.

Comment: I tried that. But just replacing ```executeScript``` with ```executeAsyncScript``` does not work. The code does not finish and runs forever. I'm not sure why. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#executeAsyncScript

Answer (score 0):

try this code. you don't need to add anything. just replace your await sleep with this code.

```
        int timeOutInSeconds = 5;
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
            wait.until(expectation);
```

Comment: The readyState property is always "complete" after the document is loaded. It does not change if I scroll something.., right? So this won't work.. I want the assertion to be executed after the site is actually scrolled down.